# Why is my SD card not formatting?

Tags: filesystem, sd-card, disk-formatting

I literally tried about a millionth time that to format my card. When I got to Menu > USB Stick Format, it says that the format is confirmed, but when the local file browser is opened all files remain the same. What should I do?

EDIT: Question has been resolved.

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details; but are you sure you're not just viewing cached files in RAM (because you failed to flush/unmount the SD card first)?    The SD card maybe *toast* (no longer writable) and so changes aren't writing to it, or at least the section being written to... they are cheap/consumable media without diagnostics ..

Comment: Are you sure you're formatting the correct USB stick? 

Comment: You must `umount` the SD first. Read `man umount`.

Comment: [This link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/144852/cant-format-my-usb-drive-i-have-already-tried-with-mkdosfs-and-gparted/933035#933035) can help you analyze the problem, and if you are lucky, solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install gparted (it is in the repository) . Put your card in the machine and start gparted.  It will ask your password. THen you can see, unmount,format etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Disks" for it , select your sd card and you can find gear icon at top of the window , select format device/card , it takes some time and after that select the sdcard and again select the gear icon and select create partition , here you go...